# Windows 7 - Unidentified Network

Tags: windows-7, networking

I just installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 Pro on a computer, and plug it into the network, and it gets labeled with "Unidentified Network"

I open up the command prompt, and check "ipconfig/all", and I am getting an IP address (10.0.0.63) and DNS server (10.0.0.5) info from the DHCP server (10.0.0.200), and when I attempt to "ping google.com" I get: Pinging google.com [72.14.204.99] - Reply from 10.0.0.63 Destination Host Unreachable" So I can talk to my local DNS server, resolving a domain name, but I cannot get outside of my network from only that PC.

I can ping my DNS server,  and every other computer on the local network, but not my Gateway/Router/DHCP (10.0.0.200). So the Router is giving my computer an IP, but my computer cannot ping the device that is giving it an IP.

Is is the Windows 7 Unidentified Network label preventing my from getting outside my network, or is something else?

Also where can I find a good article explaining what this whole "Windows is identifying network" stuff is all about? Why can't it just get an IP address and be happy?

**Edit:**

When I set the IP statically instead of pulling from the DHCP server (using same values DHCP handed the PC), I get a dialog from Windows asking "Select a Location for the Network", with the choices Home/Work/Public. And now everything works fine, no more issues.

What is the deal with "Windows is identifying network" stuff?

Comment: are you sure that other computers connected to this network is working ?

Comment: yes, other computers on same switch work fine

Comment: Identifying the network is so Windows can lower the firewall settings when you're on a home network (to allow file/print sharing, etc.), and raise them when you're on a public network like a wi-fi hotspot.

Comment: and when it is "Unidentified", does that cause windows to block all traffic to the gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go into your Network and Sharing Center in Control Panel and see if you can change that unidentified network to a home network and then see if you can get online

Comment: where can I find instructions on how to do this?

Comment: Nice advice, but I couldn't find any link or button that would change it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any VLANs set up on your switch? That could cause this issue.

Comment: no VLANs on the network

Comment: Did you check for proxy setup on the computer?

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here because I had a similar issue, just inside a VM.

In case of a virtual machine (VMWare), check the network settings of VMWare. If it is set to `host only`, you do not have Internet access. Setting it to `bridged` or `NAT` will bring back the Internet connection.